# How procced cyclomatic complexity in such javascript code?

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, cyclomatic-complexity

i have some problems with complexity in my javascript. It looks like:

```
 function mainFunction(scope, element) {
        var eventHandlerMap = {
            'firstEvent': firstEventHandler,
            'secondEvent': secondEventHandler,
            .....
        };

        function firstEventHandler(element) {
            if (element) {
                //some code
            } else {
                //some code
            }
        }
        function secondEventHandler(element) {
            //some code
        }
        //and other EventHandler functions
}
```

Now mainFunction has complexity of 41, but my sonar allows no more than 10. I dont good at javascript and dont have ideas how fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way complexity is computed should be changed by next plugin version (see https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJS-729).

Answer (score 0):

Why not move firstEventHandler and secondEventHandler outside mainFunction?

If you're trying to achieve information hiding, you could use ES6 classes or use the module pattern instead of nesting the functions.